# Modify a control on an opened form from another modal form?

Tags: vb.net, telerik

How can I reference controls from another form, for example I open a modal form from another form which has a DataGrid, how can I add rows to the RadGridView from the modal form.

formA opened -> button opens formB modal -> formB code adds radgridview row to formA -> close formB -> formA has added row :)

tried from formB:

```
formA.radgridview1.rows.add("data")
```

to no avail :(

Comment: Could it be because you're missing a second set of quotation marks in the parenthesis? E.g. `("data")`

Comment: Sorry, missed the quotes here :)

Comment: Okay, so the quotes were in your original code when you were having the error then? Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: What do you bind to the DataGrid?, is it a DataTable?

Comment: What does "to no avail" mean? Do you get an error? I did this in a new project with just two forms and a text box and it worked, i.e., using Form1.TextBox1.Text = "foo" form Form2 opened modally updated the text box. Using VS2010

Comment: nope, the datagrid ain´t binded, it is a datatable

Comment: I also don´t what "to no avail" means, its used for no luck matters i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the DataTable that you use as a datasource of the RadGridView as Public inside the Form1 and inside the Form2 add rows to the DataTable instead of the RadGridView.

Inside Form1

```
Public DataTable1 As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataTable1.Columns.Add("data")
    DataTable1.Rows.Add("Test row from Form A")
    RadGridView1.DataSource = DataTable1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Form2 As New Form2
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    Form2.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Inside Form2

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.DataTable1.Rows.Add("Test row from Form B")
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a new project, add the above code and run it. If it succeeds then it will be easier to locate the flaw in your current project.